# Problems with Path.js for jQuery back plugin

Tags: ajax, refresh, path.js

I have decided upon path.js to use as my jQuery plugin for back/reload functionality, it is almost up and running but won't seem to work. A link to the plugin: https://github.com/mtrpcic/pathjs

Head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="back.js"></script>
```

Navigation:

```
<div id="leftnav">
        <p class="leftnavtext">
            <a class="navlinks" id="about2" href="#/about">ABOUT</a> <br>
            <a class="navlinks" id="process2" href="#/process">PROCESS</a> <br>
            <a class="navlinks" id="materials2" href="#/materials">MATERIALS</a> <br>
            <a class="navlinks" id="pricing2" href="#/pricing">PRICING</a>
        </p>
```

AJAX Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#about2").click(function(){
    $("#content").load("content.html #about");
});
  $("#process2").click(function(){ 
    $("#content").load("content.html #process");
 });
  $("#materials2").click(function(){ 
    $("#content").load("content.html #materials");
});
  $("#pricing2").click(function(){
    $("#content").load("content.html #pricing");
 });
   $("#pricing3").click(function(){
    $("#content").load("content.html #pricing");
});
   $("#infinite1").click(function(){
    $("#content").load("content.html #infinite");
});


});
```

Path.js Code (back.js in header, path.js is the plugin.):

```
function notFound(){
            $("#content .content").html("404 Not Found");
            $("#content .content").addClass("Error");
        }

        function setPageBackground(){
            $("#content .content").removeClass("Error");
        }        

        Path.map("#/about").to(function(){
            $("#content .content").html("About");
        }).enter(setPageBackground);

       Path.map("#/process").to(function(){
            $("#content .content").html("Process");
        }).enter(setPageBackground);

       Path.map("#/materials").to(function(){
            $("#content .content").html("Materials");
        }).enter(setPageBackground);

       Path.map("#/pricing").to(function(){
            $("#content .content").html("Pricing");
        }).enter(setPageBackground);


        Path.root("#/about");
        Path.rescue(notFound);

        $(document).ready(function(){

            Path.listen();
 });
```

Can anyone see where im going wrong with this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to navigate directly to `/#/materials` by entering the url in your browser address bar, [according to the author](https://github.com/mtrpcic/pathjs/issues/31#issuecomment-6660068) PathJS doesn't currently support this as it is meant for clientside routing only.

I got round this by including `Path.history.pushState({}, "", location.hash);` in my onload script.